# Displaying the background page without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm facing a problem, which is when I insert a background to my HTML page, the background doesn't appear. The page should be refreshed to display the  background. I don't have any idea of the problem,  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
        <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $("document").ready(function(){
           $("#page6").css("background-image","url('http://up.arabseyes.com/uploads2013/29_04_16146193093279651.jpg')");
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id = "page6" data-role="page">
            <div id="header" >
                <center>
        <h1>Contact</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
                <div data-role= "contenet">

<FORM action="mailto:youremail@hotmai.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4" WIDTH="90%">
                            <TR>
                                <TD width="30%">
                                <DIV align="right">
                                    <B>Name:</B>
                                </DIV></TD>
                                <TD width="70%">
                                <INPUT type="text" name="name" size="20">
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD>
                                <DIV align="right">
                                    <B>Email:</B>
                                </DIV></TD>
                                <TD>
                                <INPUT type="text" name="email" size="20">
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD>
                                <DIV align="right">
                                    <B>Message:</B>
                                </DIV></TD>
                                <TD>                                <TEXTAREA name="comment" cols="30" wrap="virtual" rows="4">
</TEXTAREA></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
                                <TD>
                                <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                                <INPUT type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
                                </TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TABLE>
                    </FORM>

                    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="b">

                        <div data-role="navbar">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="page2.html" data-icon="home" >Home</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="page3.html" data-icon="heart" >BMI</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>

                                    <a href="#page4" data-icon="user" >Records</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#page5" data-icon="bars" >Suggestions</a>

                                </li>

                                <li>

                                    <a href="#page6" data-icon="mail" >Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: whats your problem.. image is loading for the first time

Comment: instead of link image from external resource, try to test local image

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. That code works fine for me.

Comment: <div id = "page6" data-role="page"> <- Add clearfix class `.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}`

Comment: @Quentin, if you tried to link the page to another page, the background doesn't appear unless if you refresh the page.

Comment: @UdayHiwarale I didn't understand what you mean ?

Comment: @Karthikeyansundaramoorthi my problem is when I try to link the pages together and go to page 6, the background doesn't show up unless if I had to refresh the page

Comment: @MehdiDehghani the local image doesn't work

Comment: remove js and add css, say if works fine or not

Comment: @MehdiDehghani you mean I have to remove  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>   
I can't remove these codes because I should include it in my project

Comment: no, I mean you js block for adding the bg image, remove that block & use css for adding that image to bg

Comment: @MehdiDehghani can you please send me the code

Comment: I mean remove this `$("#page6").css("background-image","url('http://up.arabseyes.com/uploads2013/29_04_16146193093279651.jpg')");` & add this: `<div id = "page6" data-role="page" style="background-image:url('http://up.arabseyes.com/uploads2013/29_04_16146193093279651.jpg')">`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani still doesn't work

Comment: could you please provide an jsfiddle link, with my mentioned edit?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani https://jsfiddle.net/qa3n04jw/1/

Comment: I just opened that url (`http://up.arabseyes.com/uploads2013/29_04_161461930‌​93279651.jpg`) in browser & seems like the image doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Also I asked you, provide a fiddle, without script and using css ! I just want to know how to write your inline css.